# How to add XML element without duplication using Python

Tags: python, xml, structure, element

Using Python to extract a metadata XML file, populate various elements from the Python script, and then save the XML file back to its source. There is an existing element called 'citeinfo' that I am trying to create a couple of sub elements inside of, one called "pubdate" and another called "othercit". I'm not getting any errors when I run the script, but when I open the XML post-processing, I get a second element group for "citation", which is the parent of "citeinfo", and a single line of all of my new elements. Here's my Python:

```
import arcpy, sys  
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree  
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from arcpy import env  
env.overwriteOutput = True  
fcpath         = r"...\HL Metadata to BR Sample Data.gdb\NCI20102014_Oral"
translatorpath = r"...\Translator\ARCGIS2FGDC.xml"
xmlfile        = r"...\Extras\FullMetaFC.xml"
arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(fcpath, translatorpath, xmlfile)

tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(xmlfile)

a   = tree.find('idinfo')
aa  = tree.find('metainfo')
aaa = tree.find('eainfo')

b = ET.SubElement(a, 'citation')
c = ET.SubElement(b, 'citeinfo')
bb = ET.SubElement(c, 'pubdate')
d = ET.SubElement(c, 'othercit')
e = ET.SubElement(a, 'descript')
f = ET.SubElement(e, 'abstract')
g = ET.SubElement(e, 'purpose')

title       = tree.find("idinfo/citation/citeinfo/title")
public_date = tree.find("idinfo/citation/citeinfo/pubdate")
cit_source  = tree.find("idinfo/citation/citeinfo/othercit")
abstract    = tree.find("idinfo/descript/abstract")
purpose     = tree.find("idinfo/descript/purpose")

title.text       = "Oral Cancer Incidence by County"
bb.text = "99990088"
d.text  = "https://statecancerprofiles.cancer.gov/"
abstract.text    = "Incidence rates are..."
purpose.text     = "The State Cancer Profiles..."

tree.write(xmlfile)

arcpy.ImportMetadata_conversion(xmlfile, "FROM_FGDC", fcpath, "ENABLED")
```

Here's the XML:

```
   <citation>
      <citeinfo>
        <origin>X</origin>
        <title>META_TESTING</title>
        <geoform>vector digital data</geoform>
      <pubdate>20102010</pubdate><othercit>www.google.com</othercit></citeinfo>
    </citation>
```

I want the "citation" group to look like:

```
    <citation>
      <citeinfo>
        <title>National Cancer Institute, Oral Cancer Incidence by County</title>
        <geoform>vector digital data</geoform>
        <pubdate>20120510</pubdate>
        <othercit>www.google.com</othercit>
      </citeinfo>
    </citation>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a little helper function that ensures the existence of an element. If it exists, it returns it - if it doesn't, it creates it.

```
def ensure_elem(context, name):
    elem = context.find(name)
    return ET.SubElement(context, name) if elem is None else elem
```

Now you can do:

```
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)

# ensure we have a /metadata/idinfo/citation/citeinfo hierarchy
metadata = tree.getroot()
idinfo = ensure_elem(metadata, "idinfo")
citation = ensure_elem(idinfo, "citation")
citeinfo = ensure_elem(citation, "citeinfo")

# update the text of elements beneath citeinfo
ensure_elem(citeinfo, 'pubdate').text = "new pubdate"
ensure_elem(citeinfo, 'title').text = "new title"
# ...and so on

tree.write(xmlfile)
```

Note that you can `ET.parse()` a file in one line of code.

---

For brevity, one could do:

```
e = ensure_elem

# ensure we have a /metadata/idinfo/citation/citeinfo hierarchy
citeinfo = e(e(e(tree.getroot(), "idinfo"), "citation"), "citeinfo")
```

---

For pretty-printing an ElementTree document, you can use this function:

```
def indent(tree, indent_by='  '):
    irrelevant = lambda s: s is None or s.lstrip('\r\n\t\v ') == ''
    indent_str = lambda i: '\n' + indent_by * i

    def indent(elem, level=0, last_child=True):
        if len(elem) and irrelevant(elem.text):
            elem.text = indent_str(level+1)

        if irrelevant(elem.tail):
            elem.tail = indent_str(level-(1 if last_child else 0))

        for i, child in enumerate(elem, 1):
            indent(child, level+1, i==len(elem))

    indent(tree.getroot())
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's almost there. Now its in the Citation container, but its at the same level as Citeinfo, when it should be a child of Citeinfo. Also, the new elements are all on one line, how would I get pubdate on one, and othercit on another?

Comment: It's impossible that they are on the same level, the `ensure_elem` function creates only children. Look again. They are on the same line because indentation must explicitly be added to the tree, it does not magically appear on its own. Search for "How to pretty-print XML with ElementTree".

Comment: Thanks, I think your solution will do the trick, but the prettifying is going to need another post.

Comment: I've noticed a bug in the `ensure_elem`, please use the updated version! (There are several threads on the topic of pretty-printing with ElementTree here on SO, search around. If you can use lxml, use that instead - it has pretty-printing already built in)

Comment: Also, since I did not find a pretty-printing function for ElementTree that I liked a 100% here on SO, I've created one. You can use that.

Comment: Would the prettifying happen before or after "tree.write(xmlfile)"? what has to happen to change this to commit the prettifying? I think I'm stuck on the logic of this part.

Comment: If i run the code with the prettifying part, it doesn't fix it, but if I run it a second time without edits, it does. Not sure what's going on, but after the second run, it gives me what I need.

Comment: Adding elements -> adding whitespace ("pretty-printing") -> writing to file.

Comment: That's how I have it in the script, but it's still not indenting properly. Do I have to change anything in your prettifying definition to connect to other pieces?

Comment: You have to call the function, are you doing that?

Comment: I think what I'm asking is how to call the function with the writing to file part?

Comment: Well... `indent(tree)`, then `tree.write(xmlfile)`.

Comment: If this works for you, please mark this answer as aceepted.